# How were matters left after the single Tyrion/ Varys / Kinvara talk in Season 6?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Kinvara (high-ranking Red Priestess) was in only one scene in Season 6 ("The Door"). The scene was a discussion with Tyrion and Varys about how to calm the civil unrest in Meereen. After that, nothing. There was no more mention directly, or obliquely, of the Red Priestesses (other than Melisandre) in Season 6.

So, what is going on with the Red Priestesses of Volantis? Did the discussion with Varys and Tyrion mean anything? There is so much material to cover in so little time, that could not have been a no-op. So, why have that scene?

Comment: ["In the streets of Meereen, the Red Priestesses preach that Daenerys Targaryen has been sent by R'hllor to end slavery. Tyrion Lannister and Varys enter the market place where they debate the merits of Tyrion's hiring of "fanatics" to keep order on Meereen."](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/No_One#In_Meereen)

Comment: Had to downvote because the premise of the question is wrong. Despite your claim that we never saw or heard from other Red Priestesses again in Season Six, this matter was directly addressed in a later episode, in which the Red Priestess was not only mentioned, but also seen and heard. The characters you mention then _openly discuss the results of the talk_. So, y'know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah. yeah. I don't have perfect memory. But, imho, the danger of Tyrion's overruling Varys' much better judgement should have been stressed enough to remember next April.  2nd Sons vs. Red Priestesses for control of Meereen is a major plot line I expect.

Comment: @khyle: Yeah you could be right.

Comment: A state religion? Sure, why not? It worked well for Cersei, after all. And for Stannis.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm thinking, just like every power centre (except the Vale), Meereen will be controlled by the women. But... I never got a feel for Meereen as a city, unlike Qarth, Astapor, and Bravos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [scene from S06E08](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yh8nhB9wiQ8), *No One*,  below shows that the plan did work. We see Tyrion and Varys walking through the markets and notice a Red Priestess with many gathered around her. Tyrion remarks...

> Tyrion: I call that a successful gambit.
>
> Varys: Would you?
>
> Tyrion: Look around the city has come back to life.
>
> Varys: You made a pact with fanatics...
>
> Tyrion: I did. And it worked.
>
> Varys: If you shaved you beard with a straight razor, you'd say the razor worked. That doesn't mean it won't cut your throat.
>
> Tyrion: Spoken like a man who has never had to shave.

**We will just have to see if the plans ends up costing him at some point...**